# error in plugin JUCMNav eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am trying to add jUCMNav to eclipse, and I am getting this error:

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: jUCMNav: URN Editor (UCM and GRL) 6.0.0 (seg.jUCMNav.feature.group 6.0.0)
  Missing requirement: jUCMNav 6.0.0 (seg.jUCMNav 6.0.0) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts 1.3.1' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: jUCMNav: URN Editor (UCM and GRL) 6.0.0 (seg.jUCMNav.feature.group 6.0.0)
    To: seg.jUCMNav [6.0.0]

what should I do to complete the installation ? any help is much appreciated

PS: the link that I added for the installation is : 
   http://jucmnav.softwareengineering.ca/jucmnav/updatesite/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when i was using eclipse Indigo.
I took the latest version of eclipse and it worked fine.